# how to select/add a column to pandas dataframe based on a non trivial function of other columns

Tags: function, select, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

This is a followup question for this one: [how to select/add a column to pandas dataframe based on a function of other columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911546/how-to-select-add-a-column-to-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-function-of-other-colu)

have a data frame and I want to select the rows that match some criteria. The criteria is a function of values of other columns and some additional values.

Here is a toy example:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
               'B': [randint(1,9) for x in xrange(9)],
               'C': [4,10,3,5,4,5,3,7,1]})
>>
   A  B   C
0  1  6   4
1  2  8  10
2  3  8   3
3  4  4   5
4  5  2   4
5  6  1   5
6  7  1   3
7  8  2   7
8  9  8   1
```

I want select all rows for which some non trivial function returns true, e.g. f(a,c,L), where L is a list of lists and f returns True iff a and c are not part of the same sublist.
That is, if L = [[1,2,3],[4,2,10],[8,7,5,6,9]] I want to get:

```
   A  B   C
0  1  6   4
3  4  4   5
4  5  2   4
6  7  1   3
8  9  8   1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **VERY VERY** hacky and non-elegant solution. As another disclaimer, since your question doesn't state what you want to do if a number in the column is in none of the sub lists this code doesn't handle that in any real way besides any default functionality within `isin()`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
               'B': [6,8,8,4,2,1,1,2,8],
               'C': [4,10,3,5,4,5,3,7,1]})

L = [[1,2,3],[4,2,10],[8,7,5,6,9]]


df['passed1'] = df['A'].isin(L[0])
df['passed2'] = df['C'].isin(L[0])
df['1&2'] = (df['passed1'] ^ df['passed2'])

df['passed4'] = df['A'].isin(L[1])
df['passed5'] = df['C'].isin(L[1])
df['4&5'] = (df['passed4'] ^ df['passed5'])

df['passed7'] = df['A'].isin(L[2])
df['passed8'] = df['C'].isin(L[2])
df['7&8'] = (df['passed7'] ^ df['passed8'])

df['PASSED'] = df['1&2'] & df['4&5'] ^ df['7&8'] 

del df['passed1'],  df['passed2'], df['1&2'], df['passed4'], df['passed5'], df['4&5'], df['passed7'], df['passed8'], df['7&8']
df = df[df['PASSED'] == True]
del df['PASSED']
```

With an output that looks like:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   6   4
3   4   4   5
4   5   2   4
6   7   1   3
8   9   8   1
```

I implemented this rather quickly hence the utter and complete ugliness of this code, but I believe you can refactor it any way you would like (e.g. iterate over the original set of lists with `for sub_list in L`, improve variable names, come up with a better solution, etc).

Hope this helps. Oh, and did I mention this was hacky and not very good code? Because it is.

Comment: thanks! I do have hacky solutions of my own (adding columns or iterating explicitly on indices) and they are indeed not-so-elegant. I was wondering whether there is some nice solution that can take the function and do it elegantly.

Comment: I suppose you could always define a function `f` that accepts the parameters of column `A`, column `C`, and column `L` and then `apply` it to your data frame. See --> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html